# Configuring Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to use exception handler

Tags: spring, spring-security, exception

**Spring Boot here.** I just read this [excellent Baeldung article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication) on Spring Security and implementing basic auth with it. I'm interested in implementing it for a simple REST service (so *no* UI/webapp) that I need to build.

I'm particularly interested in the `BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint` impl. In this impl's `commence` override, the author:

1. Adds a `WWW-Authenticate` header to the response; and
2. Sets the HTTP status code on the response; and
3. Writes the actual response entity directly to the response; and
4. Sets the name of the realm

I want to follow this author's example to implement basic auth for my app, but I already have a perfectly functioning `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` working for my app:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyAppExceptionMapper extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse> handleIllegalArgumentExeption(IllegalArgumentException iaEx) {
        return new ResponseEntity<ErrorResponse>(buildErrorResponse(iaEx,
                iaEx.message,
                "Please check your request and make sure it contains a valid entity/body."),
            HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    // other exceptions handled down here, etc.

    // TODO: Handle Spring Security-related auth exceptions as well!
}
```

**Is there any way to tie Spring Security and Basic Auth fails into my existing/working `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler`?**

Ideally there's a way to tie my `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` impl into the exception handler such that failed authentication or authorization attempts throw exceptions that are then caught by my exception handler.

My motivation for doing this would be so that my exception handler is the central location for managing and configuring the HTTP response when *any* exception occurs, whether its auth-related or not.

Is this possible to do, if so, how? And if it is possible, would I need to still add that `WWW-Authenticate` to the response in my exception handler (why/why not)? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are wrong. Spring and Spring Security (was ACEGI) are different projects with different history. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Security). Therefore the integration is not perfect.

Comment: I agree with your view as Spring user, but seeing the history it is not strange (and that is my point). A lot of the core parts of Spring Security are still from ACEGI. If you have a problem with it, you can try to change Spring Security (be a committer or at least create a feature request), live with it or don't use Spring at all.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible. Spring security is applied as a ServletFilter, way before the request ever reaches any `@Controller` annotated class - thus exceptions thrown by Spring Security cannot be caught by an exception handler (annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`).

Having had a similar problem, I ended up using a custom `org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint` which sends an error, which in turn is forwarded to a custom `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController`